# Searching for phonenumber in database with regex

Tags: php, sql

I need to search in a database for a phonenumber. 
However, I don't know how the phone number is stored in the database, this can be in different ways, like:

```
  0123456789 
  012 3456789 
  012 34 56 78 9 
  012-3456789
```

The string that I have to look for is always formatted like

```
 0123456789
```

My query now looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM account WHERE phonenumber = '0123456789'
```

But this ofcourse only works when the phonenumber is formatted like the search string. 
How do I use a regex of other function to search for all kind of formatted phonenumbers?

Comment: Take a look at the native SQL `LIKE` operator - it's not regex but it will allow you to match patterns. http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to perform REGEXP's in MySql, I don't think its a very solid solution and the expression will be hard to tune.

```
SELECT * FROM account WHERE phonenumber REGEXP '^([0-9]{1}( |-|)){9}[0-9]{1}$'
```

A good tool to test expressions is this site: http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

The trick is to normalize your data before you enter in in your database which means strip the telephone number of all non numeric characters.

You'll need to fix the numbers already in the table too.

Best way is to store the data normalized, i.e.: Country + area + number separately .

Comment: I understand that the best way is to put the data in the database with a given format. But the point is that I have no influence on putting this data in the database. I can only read from this database! I'm going to try your answer, let you know if it worked for me!

Comment: You will probably end up with an expression like this: /([0-9]{1}( |-|)){9}[0-9]{1}/ (slightly borrowed from Daniels Pitkevičs). This matches all your examples. But i'm not a regex guru.

A good tool to test expressions is this site: http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

-- Added this to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Use Mysql REGEXP. This is a basic example of how You can achieve that. Works with every number format in Your example.
Think of better regexp to be more precise.

```
SELECT * FROM account WHERE phonenumber REGEXP '012( |-|)34( |)56( |)78( |)9';
```